# Visual Studio - "Unknown Compiler version" after upgrading

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a Visual Studio 2015 C++ project which I wanted to upgrade to VS 2017. I had already denied the automatic prompts to upgrade my project when I first opened my project in VS 2017 (wasn't sure I wanted to upgrade at the time) so I couldn't update my project that way. Instead, I just went to my project's:

Properties->Configuration Properties->General

And in there I updated the 'Platform Toolset' option to 'Visual Studio 2017 (v141)' and also changed the 'Window SDK Version' to 10.0.16299.0 from windows 8.1. After performing this manual upgrade I now get the warning when building:

```
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
```

Why am I getting this warning? I thought by changing the 'Platform Toolset' to VS2017 I would be using the VC2017 compiler. How do I fix this warning?

Comment: Boost? Qt? Other libs?

Comment: Using portions of the boost library such as outcome, smallvector and others as well as a logging library (spdlog), and same game development related libraries (SDL, GLEW, GLM).

Comment: You probably should upgrade to latest version of boost, which contains `Update last known MSVC version.`

Comment: Okay. So these warnings are most likely coming from boost then?

Comment: This line is from `boost/config/compiler/visualc.hpp`

Comment: @VTT I see. Well I guess that solves it. Thank you. If you put the 'upgrading to latest version of boost' comment as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This line is from `boost/config/compiler/visualc.hpp` so the solution would be to upgrade to the boost 1.65.1 which properly acknowledges new version of Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: I get this warning with VS 2017 and boost 1.65.1.

Comment: Exact. It depends on the Visual Studio Service Pack version (See version.hpp)
`// last known and checked version is 19.11.25506 (VC++ 2017.3):`
`#if (_MSC_VER > 1911)`